# Episys support for Atlassian's Statuspage application

Tags: statuspage-api

We are attempting to add our Episys environment to our Atlassian Statuspage implementation. Atlassian does not have an add-on component within the out-of-the-box components for Episys, you must interact with Episys through API(s).  Does anyone have experience with Episys APIs that might provide status of the Episys system?